# Not touching the views in doInBackground but still getting this crash logs "android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: "

Tags: android, android-asynctask, crash, thread-exceptions

I have gone through all the questions related to this crash `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException:`
but all the questions are using views in doInBackground which cause the exception but i am getting the exception that points towards onPostExecute method, as of i know we can utilise views in onPostExecute method of AsyncTask

Here is the crash logs.

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: 
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread (ViewRootImpl.java:7777)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie (ViewRootImpl.java:6723)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.die (ViewRootImpl.java:6708)
      at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeViewLocked (WindowManagerGlobal.java:478)
      at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView (WindowManagerGlobal.java:409)
      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate (WindowManagerImpl.java:124)
      at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog (Dialog.java:418)
      at android.app.Dialog.dismiss (Dialog.java:401)
      at com.b******.*********.*******.FacebookActivity$async.onPostExecute (FacebookActivity.java:173)
      at com.b******.*********.*******.FacebookActivity$async.onPostExecute (FacebookActivity.java:2)
      at android.os.AsyncTask.finish (AsyncTask.java:695)
      at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1 (Unknown Source)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage (AsyncTask.java:712)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:166)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6861)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:450)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Here is the onPostExecute method of AsyncTask which this crash points to

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String output) {
        super.onPostExecute(output);

        HTML = output;
        videosList.clear();
        // check if no video than give nextTry to true

        videosList = getRegexBackArray(xmlCharacterConverter(HTML), "\"(http([^\"]+)?\\.mp4([^\"]+)?)\"");

        if(nextTry == 0 && videosList.size() == 0){
            nextTry = 1;
            runAsync(website , "get" , getUserAgent("Desktop"));
        }else if(videosList.size() > 0){
            nextTry = 0;
            if(active){
                if(MainActivity.counter != 10){
                    MainActivity.counter++;
                }
                mDialogAdvance();
            }else{
                mDialog = true;
            }
        }else {

            if(!m3u8.isEmpty()) {

                new FacebookActivity.asyncm3u8().execute(m3u8, "get", "");

            }else{

                if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

                Toast.makeText(FacebookActivity.this , "We didn't found your videos. can you try other Link ?. " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the doInBackground code.

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder("");
        BufferedReader reader;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        try {

            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod(params[1].toUpperCase());
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent" , params[2]);
            urlConnection.setUseCaches( false );
            urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);


            boolean redirect = false;

            int status = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
                        || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
                        || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
                    redirect = true;
            }

            if (redirect) {

                String newUrl = urlConnection.getHeaderField("Location");
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(newUrl).openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod(params[1].toUpperCase());
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5500);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5500);
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent" , "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36");
                urlConnection.setUseCaches( false );
                urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);

            }

            try {

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    response.append(line).append("\n");
                }


                reader.close();

            }catch(Exception j){

                return "";

            } finally {

                urlConnection.disconnect();

            }

        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response.toString();
    }
}
```

Any help would be highly Appreciated.

Comment: Can you also post your `doInBackground()` snippet?

Comment: Updated please check again.

Comment: `runAsync()` method call in the `onPostExecute` is a recursion to the same async task?

Comment: Please add the code where you show the dialog.

Comment: @greeble31 here is the code to dismiss dialog in onPostExecute()

else{

                if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

                Toast.makeText(FacebookActivity.this , "We didn't found your videos. can you try other Link ?. " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

Comment: @PSandeshBaliga Yes it is recursion to the same async task.
public void runAsync(String url , String  method, String userAgent){
        website = url;
        new async().execute(url , method , userAgent);
    }

Comment: @UniqueIdentifier that's the code to dismiss the progress dialog. I'm talking about the code to _show_ it. You can edit your question to include that information, no need to put it in a comment.

Comment: Dialog doesn't being shown in the onPostExecute so i guess it's irrelevant.